# ClickOnce Looking for Update in Local Build Folder

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, clickonce, publishing

I've built a ClickOnce vsto add-in for Outlook and I was able to publish it to a network directory and install it. I can publish updates/revisions. However, when I restart Outlook after a revision, it gives me the following error:

[image]

It's basically looking for the update in the project's debug folder. What do I do to change this to the network folder? It also seems to be prepending "file:///".

Comment: `file://` is the protocol, that is expected. You'll probably need to open up the Windows Registry editor (`regedit`) and search and delete those entries from Outlook's configuration. I don't remember the exact path but there's plenty of information online - this is a common problem

Comment: It's because you ran the build in visual studio on the VSTO project which installs it from your project location. You will need to then remove it from your development machine before installing using the click once install. Open outlook and remove the addin.

Comment: Uninstalling removed all the registry data for the add-in. When I installed the add-in with the setup.exe, it would put in the network file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry key that was being affected is:
**\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\?_Outlook_AddIn\Manifest** ([See link for MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019))

Every time I published the add-in, Visual Studio would change the above registry to my local debug folder. This is only a problem if you're publishing and installing the add-in on the same computer.

To fix this, I saved the original path after installing the add-in, which would be the network folder. Published an update. Visual Studio would change the registry to the local debug folder, which I then changed back to the network drive ( this is the base folder I specified as the **Publishing Folder Location**).